# pythonの例外処理は遅くない？

Tags: python, python3, exception

今までC++やC#を触っていたのですが、たまにpythonも触っていました。

先日pythonのイテレータを見ていたら、イテレータの終了が`raise StopIteration()`で規定されていて、違和感を感じました。

C#等では「例外のcatchはかなり遅い」というのが常識だと思っていました。
少なくとも、こういう場面で安易に用いるようなものではないと思います。

もしかして、pythonでは例外処理はそこまで遅くないのでしょうか？高頻度で`raise`しても大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: related: [Would a StopIteration make python slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115954/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

同じ質問が英語の方でありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115954/would-a-stopiteration-make-python-slow

要は `StopIteration` に関してはコストが大きくならないように対処されていて、そのへんはPEP0234で言及されているとのことです。
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/
Pythonでもほかの例外の捕捉のコストは基本大きいですよ。ドキュメントに書いてあるとおり、

> 実際に例外を捕捉するのは**高価**です。

(※ただし `StopIteration` は除く)
です。

Comment: 英語の方の重複は確認していませんでした。イテレータだけ特別扱いされるのですね。StopIteration以外は、他の言語と同様に例外処理を利用することにします。

Answer (score 2):

Pythonの例外はゼロコストではないものの、高価でもない、と言われています。

- [例外はどれくらい速いのですか？](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions)

> try/except ブロックは例外が送出されなければ極端に効率的です。実際に例外を捕捉するのは高価です。

- [Cost of exception handlers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522005/cost-of-exception-handlers-in-python)

実際に計測した例。

Comment: C#で実際に計測してみましたが、1回例外をcatchするのに2μsほどでした。それと比べると確かに速いようです、

Comment: (途中で送信されてしまいました)2番目のリンクによると、pythonではその1/4程度ですね。例外処理にしては速いですが、無視できるコストではないように思います。スクリプト言語で元が遅いから問題ない、という認識で良いでしょうか？